# Some extras are null, but other works

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send `Extra` to `intent`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OpenBroadcastReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("url", url);
i.putExtra("lid", lid);
i.putExtra("regId", regId);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
```

And I get:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ShareExternalServer appUtil = new ShareExternalServer();
    Bundle extra=intent.getExtras();
    final String lid = extra.getString("lid");
    Log.e("AppUtil", "Receive! LID="+lid);
    final String url = extra.getString("url");
    final String regId = extra.getString("regId");
    Log.e("AppUtil", "Receive! URL="+url);
    Log.e("AppUtil", "Receive! regId="+regId);
```

...

```
E/AppUtil﹕ Receive! LID=null
E/AppUtil﹕ Receive! URL=https://pushall.ru/
E/AppUtil﹕ Receive! regId=APA91bGCpJWveKUgm0
```

All normal - lid dont send. All String.

Comment: your extra is well received in onReceive , I think your `lid` var is null before sending the extra. Try to send a simple string : `i.putExtra("lid", "some string");` to ensure that `lid` is not null

Comment: @S.Thiongane strange...Receive! LID=null, i set     i.putExtra("lid", "some string");

Comment: really strange :) ... ok try to change the `lid` key by another one. `i.putExtra("some_key", "some string");` and `extra.getString("some_key")` and run into your device to test.

Comment: @S.Thiongane
Receive! LID=null LID2=null
Receive! SOME_KEY=null
private void sendNotification(String msg, String n, String url, String title, final String lid, Bitmap icon) {
it can affect?

Comment: Could you try constructing your `PendingIntent` such as `PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` or other flags available

Comment: @S.Thiongane I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

For broadcast need

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.bupyc.pushall.app.CANCEL");
```

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers